# I can't seem to fix the padding around my pictures, and my footer

Tags: html, css

The pictures are supposed to have padding on around them, and the footer is supposed to be in the bottom right corner.

I haven't tried anything else because I'm not sure what the issue is.

check the comment below for the code, I have to display it this way in order to display what I'm talking about properly.

What it's supposed to look like;
https://college.cengage.com/nextbook/shared/computer_sciences/carey_9781305503939/images/83908-mod3-fig03-67-t3.png

I'll try my best, but like I previously mentioned, I can't properly explain the issue for I don't even understand what is causing it.

*"Go to the DIV Container Styles section. Richard wants you to add some additional spacing between the images and the edge of the page body. To add this spacing, create a style rule that sets the right and bottom padding of the div element with the id container to 8 pixels."*

```
div#container {
padding-right: 8px;
padding-bottom: 8px;
}
```

is what I did to try and fulfill this. 
The only thing I can think of that could be affecting this is this;

```
div[class^="column"] {
float:left;
}
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/Ulthraun/project/editor/DamNpw

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I did include the desired behavior with a picture because I can't personally explain it. I've only been doing html for a month now and honestly, layouts.css for a week.

Comment: Based on a discord channel I'm also talking with indicates that the pictures aren't flowing correctly and that they generally adjust automatically.

Comment: We don't debug pictures. Post a [mcve] **in your question** please

Comment: Also, the link doesn't work, it requires being logged on. Not that you should put an image link in the first place.

Comment: I am looking at the link you sent and the container does have a bottom and right padding of 8px.